# Flutter hive delete not working in Firebase background Message Handler

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Hive delete is not working when app receive push notification in **background or terminated** state. I am using below code.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
.
.
//few lines of code
.
.


Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async { 
  if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
    final Directory appDocDirectory =
        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    globals.hiveBoxesPath = appDocDirectory.path + '/boxes';
    Hive.init(globals.hiveBoxesPath);
  }
  BoxConstants.registerHiveAdapters();
   String mappingId = '';
    if (message.isNotEmpty && message.containsKey('data')) {
      final data = message['data'];
      final otherData =
          data.containsKey('other') ? json.decode(data['other']) : null;
      mappingId = otherData != null && otherData.containsKey('mapping_id')
          ? otherData['mapping_id'].toString()
          : mappingId;
    } else {
      final otherData =
          message.containsKey('other') ? json.decode(message['other']) : null;
      mappingId = otherData != null && otherData.containsKey('mapping_id')
          ? otherData['mapping_id'].toString()
          : mappingId;
    }
 //---- EDIT
    if (mappingId.isNotEmpty) {
  final String name = (OrgMemberUserBox).toString();
  if (Hive.isBoxOpen(name)) {
    Hive.box(name).close();
  }
  await HiveDbManager.openBox<OrgMemberUserBox>().then((box) async {
    await box.delete(mappingId);
  });
}
}
```

Above method is called when device receive notification. I am trying to deleting by key `mappingId` but it is not working.

Any solution on this?

Comment: use hivedb.delete(recursive: true);

Comment: I don't want to delete entire db.

Answer (score 0):

`onBackgroundMessage` will spawn an isolate to run the method you've passed. It has been mentioned that to use Hive in another process you would need to close the boxes from your main isolate beforehand.

Here's the [statement from Simon Leier](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/122#issuecomment-552554764), maintainer on the HiveDB repository:

> Unfortunately, Hive does not support opening boxes in multiple
> isolates. That means you can either close the box in the main isolate,
> update it in your background isolate and reopen it in the main isolate
> or you pass the data from the background to the main isolate and
> perform the update there...

Moreover you are using `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` from the package path_provider which currently seems to not be able to run inside an isolate. You can follow those GitHub issues on the Flutter repository that were opened to inform of this problem:

- [path_provider getApplicationDocumentsDirectory is broken in isolate](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28981)
- [Trouble with using path_provider package in an isolate](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51685)

But unfortunately there hasn't been a lot of progress made on this so far.

Comment: I am trying to close the box and then reopen box again in background method. It is giving an error `Box has already been closed`.

Comment: @Ajay can you update your question with a code sample of how you are closing your box ?

Comment: Please check my edit. `openBox` method open box again.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @Ajay sorry, didn't have the time to make a test project, I will be looking into it when I have a bit of time.

Comment: I've simulated this way, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I couldn't confirm whether it was true that Hive didn't support multiple isolations, but I tried to close the box over and then open it in the background for use, but that didn't work.